# iOS: index from tableView in Unit Test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a question about Unit Test. 
In one of my test I have something like that:

```
let obj = array.findElementFromIndex(index)
XCAssertNotNil(obj)
```

I want to check if my `obj` is not nil, but the `index` is from the row of tableView that I select. 
So in the Unit Test how can I take the information about the index of row that i selected to check if the object is or not null?

Thanks

Comment: Hard code an index?  Take a random index between 0 and the number of items?

Comment: are u sure that is the best implementation?

Comment: No, but it isn't really clear what you are trying to test

Comment: take this example: I am selecting a row in a tableView and I have to get an object from an array with the index of the tableview selected. I want only test if the object that I get is nil or not. That's it

Comment: OK, so that comes back to my original suggestion - how are you simulating the row that was selected? Your only two options are hard-coded or random.  Or put it another way, you have a function that, given an index in the range 0..n should return an object from an array of size n+1.  The two tests that make sense for the function are "index between 0 and n returns non-nil" and "index <0 or >n-1 returns nil".  The tableview is irrelevant

Comment: I tried to do this with a random function ad you're right. But if the array is empty the test fails :-(.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116327/discussion-between-paulw11-and-naz).